# Extending SpendFunds Type For Use w/ Multiple Pallets

Tags: relay-chain, pallet-treasury

We are building [a pallet](https://github.com/SequesterChain/pallets/blob/main/donations/src/lib.rs) that uses the [SpendFunds variable](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L547-L552) to withdraw funds from Treasuries on chains that implement it. However, with the current implementation of the SpendFunds callback, only 1 pallet can use this technique. Since all of the Relay Chains implement the [Bounties pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L858), this means that Relay chains will not be able to implement our pallet (this pallet is being developed for use by all chains, including Relay Chains).

Can we extend the [SpendFunds](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L196) type to be an Array of pallets that implement the SpendFunds trait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpendFunds` trait supports a tuple of up to 30 pallets:

```rust
#[impl_trait_for_tuples::impl_for_tuples(30)]
pub trait SpendFunds<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> {
    fn spend_funds( ... );
}
```

This means you can configure the `SpendFunds` associated type something like:

```rust
type SpendFunds = (PalletA, PalletB, PalletC);
```

Assuming Pallet A, B, and C all implement the `SpendFunds` trait. The pallets will be called in that order, each with the opportunity to spend some of the treasury funds.